# cursor showing on jquery datepicker input in IE - Readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cursor showing on ReadOnly Input in IE only. I try to disable the input but this jquery datepicker it is disabling everything.

I tried KeyCode===8 and return false. User complaining they are doing back space it is go to previous page.

```
<input name="BirthDate" class="SPE-Formcontrol section_detail-font-14 calendar hasDatepicker" id="BirthDate" 
            style="display: inline;" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="">
```

I don't see any valid answers for this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the attribute "disabled" because the input would not be submitted when it is part of a form

```js
$('#BirthDate').focus(function(){
    this.blur();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="BirthDate" class="SPE-Formcontrol section_detail-font-14 calendar hasDatepicker" id="BirthDate" 
            style="display: inline;" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="">
```

Comment: @sammu , the above backspace let you allow to go previous page. I would like to stop that to go.